# Unique File ID for Excel Files in R

Tags: r, excel, windows

I want to import a list of excel files with a unique identifier into R.

I thought of using File Name (basename(File)), however there is the potential of the file name changing and introducing duplicates into the data.

Next option would be Created Time, but that comes with it's own issues.

Is there a unique file ID for excel files that remains the same when moved and renamed? and can that ID be retrieved within R?

Comment: You can juts assign a unique number 1 - filename1, 2 - filename2 and so on. However, this could be impacted if you rename the filename.

Comment: @RonakShah Hey Ronak, I am chasing an ID for the file, because as you said this will be impacted if the file is renamed. I am looking for a persistent way to identify a file that remains the same after a file is renamed.

Comment: NTFS [stores a file ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/ns-fileapi-by_handle_file_information) that allows you to uniquely identify a file. The file ID doesn't change during file rename operations.

Comment: @IInspectable I think this would of worked if there was a way to retrieve this file ID within R. However, to add another layer - the files are stored in Sharepoint Online which i think operates differently to NTFS.